# Implementing Logistic Regression using Ridge in R but getting negative outputs?

Tags: r, logistic, regularization

I am trying to implement some logistic regression using ridge in R for predicting company bankrupcy using a subset of [this data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Polish+companies+bankruptcy+data) but despite my best efforts and various lecture notes/online tutorials, the probability predictions it is outputting include some negative values. As far as I can see I am doing everything correctly to implement a logistic regression instead of a linear but I must be missing something. My code is below, I would really appreciate any ideas from anyone.

```
#split to test and training data
set.seed(42)
s <- floor(0.7 * nrow(company_performance))
i <- sample(seq_len(nrow(company_performance)), size = s)
comp_train <- comp_perf_fixed[i, ]
comp_test <- comp_perf_fixed[-i, ]

#some standardisation of variables before regularised regression
comp_scale <- preProcess(comp_train[,1:31], method = c('center', 'scale'))
comp_train[,1:31] <- predict(comp_scale, comp_train[,1:31])
comp_test[,1:31] <- predict(comp_scale, comp_test[,1:31])
#define the predictors and response we will use for all our models
x <- model.matrix(class~., data = comp_train)[,-1]
x.test <- model.matrix(class~., data = comp_test)[,-1]
y <- as.factor(comp_train$class)
y.test <- as.factor(comp_test$class)

#apply ridge regression
cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure="class", family = "binomial", alpha = 0)
mod.ridge.min.lambda <- glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 0,
                               lambda = cv.ridge$lambda.1se, type.measure="class")

#get predictions for the test data and see some are negative
test_pred_r <- predict(mod.ridge.min.lambda, newx = x.test)
summary(test_pred_r)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are predicting probabilities and not log odds?

Comment: Note that the `rms` package `lrm` function has ridge regression built into it.

Comment: @user2974951 thank you, this got me on the right track! The problem was with my predict method, which by default was outputting the linear predictors. I set type = 'response' within it and it is now outputtting the correct probabilities!